# Bootstrap nav pill in a table

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to use the Bootstrap Nav Pills in a table, and having the "tab buttons" in the last table's row.
Tab-content is outside of the table. I tried this but it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/wxkd6r2q/

```
    <table class="table">
  <caption>List of users</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">BUTTON HERE</a>    </td>
      <td> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">BUTTON HERE</a> </td>
      <td> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">BUTTON HERE</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...home..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...profile...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel">...contact...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work:

- The classes `nav-tabs` and `tab-content` need to be siblings to get this to work... which is by putting the table inside a div with `nav-tabs` to get this to work
- Also, the DOM elements with `data-toggle="tab"` must be siblings to each other... so we move this `data-toggle="tab"` from the `<a>` inside the `<td>` to `<td>` itself

**working snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav nav-tabs">

  <table class="table">
    <caption>List of users</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="nav nav-tabs">
        <th>3</th>
        <td data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> <a>BUTTON HERE</a> </td>
        <td data-toggle="tab" href="#profile"> <a>BUTTON HERE</a> </td>
        <td data-toggle="tab" href="#contact"> <a>BUTTON HERE</a> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...home..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...profile...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel">...contact...</div>
</div>
```

Update in light of questioner's observation on the previous code...

Comment: Thank you, but if I click on #Home, then #Profile, after that I cannot click anymore on #Home because it remains activated. You can see the same behaviour in the snippet

Comment: Hi @sparkle, I hope you're having a wonderful Christmas day... I have updated the answer in light of your very good observation, please check

Comment: Thank you. Merry Christmast too. I've just added this for formatting:  <tr class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: table-row;">